# ErrorException Trying to get property 'nom_service' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

pls help I tried the maximum ways but no result, I'm beginner in laravel!!!

*liste.blade.php*

```
        <td> {{$data->candidature->demande}} </td>

        <td> {{$data->candidature->service->nom_service}} </td>

        <td> {{$data->nom}} </td>
```

Comment: `$data->candidature->service` is apparently not an object. You'll have to figure out why

Comment: I've tried all methods but no change!

Comment: It looks like a relationship, so perhaps that candidature does not have a service. In which case, you'll need to make sure that `$data->candidature->service` is not null/empty before you try to access the property. `{{ $data->candidature->service ? $data->candidature->service->nom_service : '' }}` should do it. If you think it should exist, you'll need to look at the relationship

Comment: service and candidature are two different tables in database, knowing that every candidature must have accessed to one or many services, I tried writing the same syntax you said but the same error exists. :(

Comment: If every candidature has many services, then `service` would be an array or collection, not a single object, so would not have a nom_service. You'll need to iterate over the list of services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If service is indeed an array as said in the comments, try the following:

```
@foreach ($data->candidature->service as $service)
    <td> {{$service->nom_service}} </td>
@endforeach
```